# How do I use jQuery to select a text content from a HTML node?

Tags: jquery

How do I select the "some text" only with jQuery?

```
<p class="a">some text<a href="">some other text</a></p>
```

Here above is the code.

I guess `$('p.a').text()` is not working correctly.

```js
console.log($('p.a').text());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="a">some text<a href="">some other text</a></p>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/298750/how-do-i-select-text-nodes-with-jquery Best to use plain Javascript instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('p.a').contents().filter(function () { return this.nodeType === 1; });
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation would greatly improve its long-term value](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) by showing why this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please edit your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.

Answer (score 0):

You can have your own function to ignore the child elements

```
$.fn.ignoreChildren = function(child){
    return this.clone().find(child||">*").remove().end();
};

alert($(".a").ignoreChildren('a').text()); // Alerts 'some text'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
console.log($('p.a').contents().not($('p.a').children()).text());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="a">some text<a href="">some other text</a></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the clone method to get only main node and remove all other child node from that. Then get your content. Check below code:

```
console.log($("p.a").clone().children().remove().end().text());
```

I have checked this and it is working fine. Hope it helps you.